# How do i insert an existing values from another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

What i wanted to do here is to insert the performDate value from the table CompositionCollection to be retrieve and update into performDate in Compositions table without im having to manually type it. So the each compositions will have the value of when it gets played from the compositioncollection.

The last quote space in compositions table is for the date.

```
CREATE TABLE Compositions(
CompositionId CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
Composer VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
YearWritten VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
PerformerId CHAR(6) NULL,
PerformDate DATETIME NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_compositions PRIMARY KEY (CompositionId)
);

CREATE TABLE CompositionCollection(
ConcertId CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
CompositionId INT NOT NULL,
PerformerId CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
PerformTime TIME NOT NULL,
PerformDate DATE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pk_pTime PRIMARY KEY (PerformTime)
);


-- compositions data values
INSERT INTO Compositions VALUES 
('CC01', 'Alexander Borodin', 'Scherzo in a 
Flat', '1883', '', '2017-09-17'),
('CC02', 'Alexander Borodin', 'Symphony No 
2', '1869', '', ''),
('SC01', 'Beethoven', 'Symphony No 6', 
'1802', '', ''),
('SC02', 'Edward Elgar', 'Cello Concerto', 
'1997', '', '');

-- composition collection data values
-- All the values below is for one concert and they are all played at the 
-- same date
INSERT INTO CompositionCollection VALUES 
('123456', 'CC01', 'C012', 
'08:00:00', '2017-09-17'),
('123456', 'CC02', 'C012', 
'08:15:00', '2017-09-17'),
('123456', 'SC01', 'S512', 
'08:20:00', '2017-09-17'),
('123456', 'SC02', 'C012', 
'08:40:00', '2017-09-17');
```

Comment: Im sorry if im not clear...

Comment: How do you know when the composition was played? is it a fixed time? or there do you want to get it from `CompositionCollection` ?

Comment: yeah i want the date in the composition to be updated to the latest date in composition collection

Comment: It would be nice to see the desired result, and your best effort to date. There's an edit button for this purpose.

Comment: Also, while very rare, be aware that classical compositions are occasionally penned in collaboration.

Comment: yeah the scenario doesnt say about collaboration i think..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Trigger` :

```
CREATE TRIGGER last_played
AFTER INSERT
ON CompositionCollection FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
 UPDATE Compositions SET PerformDate = New.PerformDate WHERE CompositionId = New.CompositionId;
END;
```

More about [mySQL Triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)